# Reading music file names with c++

Tags: c++

is it at all possible to read song name from folder with c++?
Don't care about other libraries, additional programs. Have noting against them, just that I have programmed c++ for a quite time and had given a task by a friend, sounds simple, but in reality, not so, and I want to do it.
The task is to find out if the song, named in a text file, is in a folder as a .mp4, .avi....etc file. I know that, even that the names in the file and the names of songs are not exactly the same (Lower case - upper case symbols, numeration in from of the name etc), I could complete the task, if i could just read the name of the song in an array or string.
Really looking forward to this, thanks.
Choose c++, because its the most familiar to me, thought that it could be possible to read file names.

Have a great day,
-Oskars

Comment: It will be OS specific, if you want to enumerate all media files in a folder. For windows : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Answer (score 1):

Most OS provides native libraries only in C, so you will end up using library this way or another.  C++standard library does not support such filesystem library yet.

You can start with library for accessing files. One of them is [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/) There is  available [recursive directory iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator). This library is expected to be similar to library that will be defined in next C++.